# Retrieving list of Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm using the following two strips of code to retrieve a list of categories (1st code)  then displaying them in a select menu (2nd code), for my theme options page. I was wondering how I could change this code to do the same, but, retrieve custom post types instead??

*Code used to retrieve categories*

```
$tp_categories[0] = array(
'value' => 0,
'label' => ''
);
$tp_cats = get_categories(); $i = 1;
foreach( $tp_cats as $tp_cat ) :
$tp_categories[$tp_cat->cat_ID] = array(
    'value' => $tp_cat->cat_ID,
    'label' => $tp_cat->cat_name
);
$i++;
endforeach;
```

*Code used to display categories in a dropdown select menu*

```
<tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><label for="choose_cat">Choose Category</label></th>
<td>
<select id="choose_cat" name="tp_options[choose_cat]">
<?php
foreach ( $tp_categories as $category ) :
    $label = $category['label'];
    $selected = '';
    if ( $category['value'] == $settings['choose_cat'] )
        $selected = 'selected="selected"';
    echo '<option style="padding-right: 10px;" value="' . esc_attr( $category['value'] ) . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $label . '</option>';
endforeach;
?>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a core function for that: [**`get_post_types()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types):

```
<?php get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator ); ?>
```

So, for example, to return public, custom post types by name:

```
$custom_post_types = get_post_types( array(
    // Set to FALSE to return only custom post types
    '_builtin' => false,
    // Set to TRUE to return only public post types
    'public' => true
) );
```

Comment: This is the _only_ solution I've found to directly address how to omit the default post types. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use `get_post_types()` or the global variable `$wp_post_types`.

From `wp-includes/post.php`:

```
/**
 * Get a list of all registered post type objects.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Post
 * @since 2.9.0
 * @uses $wp_post_types
 * @see register_post_type
 *
 * @param array|string $args An array of key => value arguments to match against the post type objects.
 * @param string $output The type of output to return, either post type 'names' or 'objects'. 'names' is the default.
 * @param string $operator The logical operation to perform. 'or' means only one element
 *  from the array needs to match; 'and' means all elements must match. The default is 'and'.
 * @return array A list of post type names or objects
 */
function get_post_types( $args = array(), $output = 'names', $operator = 'and' ) {
    global $wp_post_types;

    $field = ('names' == $output) ? 'name' : false;

    return wp_filter_object_list($wp_post_types, $args, $operator, $field);
}
```